# Does the real number $\sup_{t∈(0,1)}θ(t)$ exist

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf, sequence-of-function

Let $x_{k}(t)>c>0$ be a bounded sequence for all $t∈(0,1)$ and all $k>0$. Here $t$ is a real parameter **never equal zero** and $c$ is a fixed real number. Then we have 
$$\liminf_{k→∞}x_{k}(t)=θ(t)>0$$
Naturally, the $\liminf$ depends on the parameter $t∈(0,1)$.

Does the real number $\sup_{t∈(0,1)}θ(t)$ exist?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit confused by the term bounded here. For me bounded means bounded below and above. If this is the case then there is some $d \in \mathbb{R}$ with
$$ 0 < c < x_k(t) < d \text{ for all } t \in (0,1), k > 0.$$
This would imply that $c \leq \theta(t) \leq d$ for all $t \in (0,1)$. In other words $\theta(t)$ would then be a bounded sequence and for such a sequence the supremum exists.

When bounded does only mean bounded below then there is an answer to this question as well. For every $t \in (0,1)$ consider the sequence $x_k(t)$ with
$$x_k(t) = c+1/t \quad \forall k>0.$$
We have $\theta(t) = c+1/t$ for all $t \in (0,1)$ and for this sequence the supremum does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know bounded and uniformly bounded？

We call $\{f_n(x)\}$ is bounded when
$$\forall n,\,\exists M(n),\,s.t.|f_n(x)|<M(n)$$

And we call $\{f_n(x)\}$ is uniformly bounded (for $n$) when
$$\exists M,\,s.t.\forall n,\,|f_n(x)|<M$$

Example:

{$\sin(nx)$}is uniformly bounded (for n) , $M=1$.

{$n\sin(nx)$}is bounded, $M(n)=n$,but isn’t uniformly bounded.

So when the $x_k(t)$ is uniformly bounded (for t), sup exists. Otherwise, no.

Now $x_k(t)$ is just bounded, we let $x_k(t)=k\sin\left(\frac{t\pi}{2}\right)+1$, now $\forall k$, $x_k(t)$ is bounded because $k\geqslant x_k(t)>\frac{1}{2}>0$, and $c=\frac 12$.

But $\forall t\in(0,1)$,     $$\limsup_{k→∞}x_{k}(t)=\lim_{k→∞}k \sin\left(\frac{t\pi}{2}\right)+1=+\infty$$
So the $\sup :s(t)$ isn’t exists.

Comment: But still there is no proof of your claims.

Comment: @Helena ok, I write an example

Comment: @Helena ok I finish update.Hope it will helpful.